# Python: is it possible to convert all import variables from a separate file into into a class variable?

Tags: python

It might be a silly thing to do in practice, but is it possible to do something like:

```
from data import myvariables

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.* = myvariables.*
```

instead of doing:

```
from data import myvariables

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = myvariables.variable1
        self.variable2 = myvariables.variable2
        ...
```

myvariables is just a file that contains a bunch of variables like `variable1 = 1; variable2 = 'string'`, etc.

Comment: I'd say that, if they come from anther module, they are not specific to a instance and shouldn't be attributs of the class, just use them when needed

Comment: That makes sense. I was toying with this idea as a temporary workaround for something, and was curious if it was even possible.

Comment: If you need this kind of behaviour (why I wouldn't even start got guess) and have full control over both classes: export a dictionary of the modules variables and import them into your other class. You are probably waaaay out of sensible land if you think you need to  do this. Read about  `**kwargs` how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs

Comment: That's a much better idea, thanks. Yeah I realise it is quite redundant

Comment: @PatrickArtner after a quick look it seems quite complicated - I have to convert all the variable names in the file into a list of strings (not easy) and it's not mutable in the same way the code works so I have to convert them back to variables after importing it. I'll think about another workaround...